# Need to show usercontrol on the top in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control that I am using for some purpose and it's movable on the screen. Actually I am creating an application using Leap Motion. SO wherever I move my figure on the screen a big circular cursor moves accordingly. But on some place it gets cut off or I would say it gets hide or overlapped due to some other controls. So I want to know, how can I placed it on the top of the mainwindow view. Is it possible using adorner layer? If yes, So can you please tell me how to do that in WPF?

I found few examples on net but they are creating a rectangle or some thing on adorner layer using drwaingcontext object, however I  just need to show my user control on the top.

Please give me some idea

Thanks & Regards,
Vinod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use the `Adorner` layer to simply show a `UserControl` on top of other controls... of course that depends on exactly what is 'overlapping' or hiding it. If they are just other UI controls, then you can fix your problem in two ways.

The first is to simply declare your `UserControl` that you want to be on top of the other controls at the bottom of the XAML, eg. define that element last.

The second solution is to use the `Panel.ZIndex Attached Property` to place that element above all others:

```
<UserControl Panel.ZIndex="10" />
```

Comment: Thanks Sheridan for the reply, however I have set it's ZIndex but still facing the same hiding problem And as far as your first suggestion is concerned so I cant set it as last element because I have created a behaviour for buttons and it' name is "ButtonHoverBehavior" and so whenever we hover the cursor over the buttons using finger point gesture it gets visible, basically it's  a circle and on hovering over button it get's visible using behavior.

Comment: @VinodBhatt Did you ever solve this?  I'm facing the same problem